# How to use query param to display filtered data using django filters?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-filters

I am kind of new to django, this is my product list view

```
filter_dict = {'category__name__in': ["Cat1", "Cat2"]}
products = Product.objects.all().filter(**filter_dict)

context = {
           'products': products
          }

return render(request, 'product_list.html', context)
```

What i want to do is to display filtered data based on user request i.e
if url is something.com/?category__name=Cat1
**Display only Cat1 products.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) is made for.

Django-Filter is a third party django app that lets you filter querysets directly from urls.